# How can I control the height of the section superstar in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, fonts

If I start Emacs (29.1 on macOS Ventura) using the `.emacs` file

```
(require 'org-superstar)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-superstar-mode 1)))

;; (set-face-attribute 'default nil :foundry "apple" :family "Monaco")
```

I get the usual and sensible line spacing that enables seeing many headings without scrolling.

[image: normal-height for section star]

Yet when I uncomment the `set-face-attribute` line, the height of the section star (and only the section star, not the subsection, etc, stars) is suddenly much larger.

(The height of `F` in `Foo` remains unchanged.)

[image: unusually tall section star]

*How can I control the height of the section superstar in org mode?*

##### It's not the same font

When I <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd> on the section superstar, I see that it's an altogether different font:

```
The component character(s) are displayed by these fonts (glyph codes):
 ◉: mac-ct:-*-Adelle Sans Devanagari-regular-normal-normal-*-62-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1 (#x28E)
See the variable ‘reference-point-alist’ for the meaning of the rule.
```

Q: Might explicitly setting the font back (to `Monaco`) solve this issue?

A: No it doesn't. Adding `'(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :weight bold :font "Monaco" :height 1.00))))` (via customization) changes nothing.

Comment: Did you try the `set-frame-font` solution from the first comment in your link?

Comment: @NickD Cool.. any hints about my main issue?

Comment: No idea - I know nothing about `org-superstar`.